# how to get a last value from Page.Request.Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, request

Request.Url
Full URL : `http://localhost:2000/virtual_dir/myrep/page.aspx?q=qvalue`

i know how to get `?q=qvalue` using `Request.Url.Query`

but i need just a `qvalue`.
how to do that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you're using MVC. In that case, you can accept query strings by using an argument on the action. Something like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string q) {...}
```

And then you just work with the variable q as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Request` or `Request.QueryString` respectively

```
var q = Request["q"];
var q = Request.QueryString["q"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var foo = Request.QueryString["q"];
```